# Convert .NET to php. Response.Redirect

Tags: php, .net, response.redirect

OK so my goal is to get this page:

`http://www.orchidfilmcompany.co.uk/Payment.aspx`

to work in my php wordpress page.

I dont really know where to start, my whole site is ready to go except for this new pay online page.

The guy who created the .NET page has provided me with the Response.Redirect code which has the merchant peoples url with instID etc. The user will be redirected to this url to complet the payment

I have been looking around online and I found the the equivelant code in php for this is:

`Header("Location: $url");`

My problem is I dont know what to do with that?

Thats all I need is input box where the user can enter the amount they want to pay, they press submit and it redirects them to the url that I have in the Response.Redirect code. Uses the amount that they entered in the box and they can complete the payment.

If anyone could assist I would really appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[header()](http://php.net/header) function is used to redirect the browser to a specific location.

If you already have the URL where you should redirect the client and you need just to add some amount that came from an input .. you should append that amount in the redirect url

eg:

purchase.html - include this form on your page

```
<form method="post action="/redirect.php">
    <input type="text" name="amount" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Purchase" />
</form>
```

redirect.php - put this file next to your html file

```
<?php
     $amount = (int) $_POST['amount'];
     $urlToRedirect = 'https://secure.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase?instId=XXX&cartId=OFMaterial&currency=GBP&amount='.$amount;
     header('Location: '.$urlToRedirect);
     exit;
?>
```

Comment: OK thanks for this. but how would i go about creating a field that has that amount in place to work? <input type="text" value="0.00" />. All of the replies here are a bit beyond me i think. I dont know where to look to get the page working. I dont know what to search for. Any ideas?

Comment: Just use: `<input type="text" name="amount value="" />`

Comment: OK cool.What about the button - what code do I use for the button in order to get it to actually send the amount to the url? - thanks for this.

Comment: OK cheers - this seems to be doing something but now I have used what you said but when I click on the page that has the form on it, I automatically get redirected to the paymentgateway page so i dont even get the opportunity to enter any amount - any ideas? - I think I didnt understand the redirect.php section.

Comment: You use that form on the first page, the PHP code I've posted is for intermediary page.

Comment: Just so you can see the .Net code which may help is: Response.Redirect("https://secure.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase?instId=XXXXXX&cartId=OFMaterial&currency=GBP&amount=" & txtAmount.Text & "&desc=Orchid%20Film%20Service\Material%20Online%20Payment&testMode=0") - i have removed their instID but the XXX's are actually numbers that I will be in.

Comment: i have tried everything to get it to show. h t t p s://secure.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase?instId=XXX&cartId=OFMaterial&currency=GBP&amount=

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15177/discussion-between-mihai-iorga-and-dan-davies)

Answer (score 0):

You could try having a form which submits to a PHP page

The PHP page could then pick up the form variables using `$_POST['FORM_VAR']`

Build a `$url` variable from the submitted variables + .net page url

Finally use the `header("Location: $url");` to take in the built url and redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The form should have an `action` assigned to it, which is the page that will parse the form.
On that page (or within your parsing bit of the code), make sure that the redirect happens there.

The header statement is correct, e.g.:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
?>
```

Would redirect to example.com. So, construct the URL you want to redirect to there.
**Please note:** header directly modifies the headers returned by your webserver and therefore it cannot be called if you already sent other (HTML) output to your browser. Also see the documentation on header here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php